# checking array value with if statement always returns (output) false (else)

Tags: php, if-statement

I've following array:

```
Array
(
    [0] =>  class="amount">€39,00
    [2] =>  class="subscription-details">
    [4] => für
    [5] => 1
    [6] => month
)
```

I want to check if the sixth element of the value is "month".

I use this code:

```
print_r($test[6]); //Output month

if($test[6] == 'month'){
    echo 'Alex'; //should output
}else{
    echo 'Ecke'; //will output
}
```

Why this code will output "Ecke" and not "Alex"?

Edit:

`var_dump($test[6])` outputs = string(12)

`var_export($test[6])` outputs = 'month'

var_export($test) =

```
<pre>array (
  0 => '<span',
  1 => 'class="amount">&euro;39,00</span>',
  2 => '<span',
  3 => 'class="subscription-details">',
  4 => 'für',
  5 => '1',
  6 => 'month</span>',
)</pre>
```

Comment: Use var_dump() rather than print_r(), that way you can tell if there are any invisible characters such as spaces in your array values

Comment: I think `var_export` for the entire array might be even better cause this allows to copy/paste the code and make a simple test :)

Comment: yes.. I edit it :p

Comment: Can you do `var_dump($test);`

Comment: The var_export show the issue.. I have to check 'month</span>' and than it works fine.

Comment: It looks like the `</span>` tag has been hidden by the browser and this is why you have missed it. Good luck :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does output Alex. Here is the simplest test case which almost repeats your code as I understand it.

```
<?php
$test = [
    0 => 'class="amount">€39,00',
    2 => 'class="subscription-details">',
    4 => 'für',
    5 => 1,
    6 => 'month</span>',
];

var_dump($test[6]);
var_export($test[6]);

if (trim(strip_tags($test[6])) == 'month') {
    echo PHP_EOL.'Alex'.PHP_EOL; //should output
} else {
    echo PHP_EOL.'Ecke'.PHP_EOL; //will output
}
```

When I run the script I get

```
string(12) "month</span>"
'month</span>'
Alex
```

Can you please show result of the `var_export` for your array. Most likely you have leading or trailing spaces in the word month. You might want to [`trim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) the string before comparing it with 'month'.

Update: I think you've answered your own question when provided `var_dump` results. The value in `$test[6]` is not a month but `month</span>`

I've updated the test for this and added [`strip_tags`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) function. This is just for fun and to show that you can easily remove extra tags.

Comment: I edit my question.. Your answer doesn't work for me.

Comment: Thank you for the tip var_export()

Answer (score 0):

Well, this seems to be a problem...

```
var_dump($test[6]) outputs = string(12)
```

`month` is not 12 characters long. You probably have some non-printable characters in that string apart from `month`